# How to pass deleter to make_shared?

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, smart-pointers, make-shared

Since C++11, because of several reasons, developers tend to use smart pointer classes for dynamic lifetime objects. And with those new smart pointer classes, standards, even suggest to not use operators like `new` instead they suggest to use `make_shared` or `make_unique` to avoid some error prone.

If we like to use a smart pointer class, like `shared_ptr`, we can construct one like,

```
shared_ptr<int> p(new int(12));
```

Also we would like to pass a custom deleter to smart pointer classes,

```
shared_ptr<int> p(new int(12), deleter);
```

On the other hand, if we like to use `make_shared` to allocate, for ex. `int`, instead of use `new` and `shared_ptr` constructor, like on the first expression above, we can use

```
auto ip = make_shared<int>(12);
```

But what if we like to also pass a custom deleter to `make_shared`, is there a right way to do that? Seems like compilers, at least gcc, gives an error to,

```
auto ip = make_shared<int>(12, deleter);
```

Comment: Write  your own `make_shared()` that supports this, it is doable.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

As other have said, `make_shared` cannot be used with a custom deleter. But I want to explain why.

Custom deleters exist because you allocated the pointer in some special way, and therefore you need to be able to deallocate it in a correspondingly special way. Well, `make_shared` allocates the pointer with `new`. Objects allocated with `new` should be deallocated with `delete`. Which the standard deleter dutifully does.

In short, if you can live with the default allocation behavior, you can live with the default *deallocation* behavior too. And if you can't live with the default allocation behavior, you should use [`allocate_shared`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/allocate_shared), which uses the provided allocator to both allocate and deallocate the storage.

Also, `make_shared` is allowed to (and almost certainly will) allocate the memory for `T` and the control block for the shared_ptr within the same allocation. This is something that your deleter can't really know about or deal with. Whereas `allocate_shared` is capable of handling it, since the allocator you provide can do allocation and deallocation duties.

Comment: Upvoted, I've never thought about that, but it makes perfectly sense. Good hint.

Comment: +1 but custom deleters aren't just for controlling deallocation, the pointer owned by a `shared_ptr` hasn't necessarily been "allocated" at all. You might want to use `fclose` to close a FILE*, for example.  Using `allocate_shared` allows you to control the memory allocation, but not use arbitrary resources. You still have to construct and destruct an object, not obtain "a resource" from a function and free it with another (deleter) function. Even if [lwg 2070](http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-active.html#2070) gets fixed that still doesn't allow custom deleters with make/allocate_shared.

Comment: The bottom line is that because make/allocate_shared don't allow you to change the "obtain a resource" step it doesn't make sense for them to support custom ways to "free the resource" either. They are used for simple create/destroy an object uses of `shared_ptr`.

Comment: Or put another way: consider an incomplete type, `X`, and functions `get()` and `put(X*)`. You can use this with `shared_ptr<X>(get(), &put)` but there's no way to use `make_shared` or `allocate_shared` because they both depend on `sizeof(X)` which is not known.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: But in those cases, you *created* the object being pointed to. So you could never use `make_shared` or `allocate_shared`, since the primary purpose of both is for *them* to create the object.

Comment: That should be the answer :) Discussing allocation and `allocate_shared` is an unnecessary diversion. The point is that make_shared creates the object so you should also trust it to "uncreate" it.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: So I should say, "In short, if you can live with the default allocation behavior, you can live with the default deallocation behavior too?" My point with `allocate_shared` is that it can be used in many cases where you want an explicit deleter. Not necessarily all, but many.

Comment: As I said, there's more to "uncreate" than deallocation, there's also a destructor, but often when you need a custom deleter it doesn't necessarily involve any destructor, or any deallocation.

Comment: _"Well, make_shared allocates the pointer with new. Objects allocated with new should be deallocated with delete. Which the standard deleter dutifully does."_ There's no guarantee make_shared uses `new`, it could allocate it with `std::allocator` (as my implementation does), or `malloc`. Or a custom allocator, or something else. You don't know, and so your deleter wouldn't know what to do. make_shared creates the object, somehow, so you should trust it to uncreate it.

Comment: I agree, accept for when it comes to threads, which need to be joined before deleted

Answer (score 13):

As from the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared), `make_shared` accepts a *list of arguments with which an instance of T will be constructed*.
Moreover, the documentation says that:

> This function is typically used to replace the construction std::shared_ptr(new T(args...)) of a shared pointer from the raw pointer returned by a call to new.

Because of that, you can deduce that you can't set a custom *deleter*.
To do that, you have to create the `shared_ptr` for yourself by means of the right [constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr).
As an example of a constructor from the proposed list, you can use:

```
template< class Y, class Deleter > 
shared_ptr( Y* ptr, Deleter d );
```

Thus, the code will be something like:

```
auto ptr = std::shared_ptr(new MyClass{arg1, arg2}, myDeleter);
```

Instead of:

```
auto ptr = std::make_shared<MyClass>(arg1, arg2);
```

Answer (score 6):

It is unspecified how `make_shared` obtains the memory for the object (it could use `operator new` or `malloc` or some kind of allocator) so there is no way a custom deleter could know how to do the right thing. `make_shared` creates the object, so you have to also rely on it to destroy the object correctly and do the appropriate clean up, whatever that is.

> Also we would like to pass a custom deleter to smart pointer classes,
>
> `shared_ptr<int> p(new int(12), deleter);`

I don't think this is a very realistic example. A custom deleter is typically used when the resource was obtained in some special way. If you just created it with `new` like this then why do you need a custom deleter anyway?

If you just want some code to be run on destruction then put it in a destructor! That way you can also still use it with `make_shared` e.g.

```
struct RunSomethingOnDestruction {
  RunSomethingOnDestruction(int n) : i(n) { }
  ~RunSomethingOnDestruction() { /* something */ }
  int i;
};

auto px = std::make_shared<RunSomethingOnDestruction>(12);
std:shared_ptr<int> p(px, px->i);
```

This gives you a `shared_ptr<int>` that is created by `make_shared` (so you get the memory optimisations done by `make_shared`) that will run some custom code on destruction.

Comment: and if you can't alter the destructor of the thing being pointed to?

Comment: Then use a custom deleter, and don't use `make_shared`.

Answer (score 4):

You can't.  `make_shared<T>` forwards the provided arguments to the constructor of type `T`.  It is used for the simple case when you want the default deleter.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a custom deleter you can't use `make_unique` or `make_shared` functions when you create a smart pointer objects . Since we need to provide our custom deleter these functions do not support that .

**Don't use make_unique or make_shared if you need a custom deleter or adopting a raw pointer from elsewhere**.

The idea is if you need a specialized way to delete your object you probably need a specialized way to create them too .

Let say we a class Test

```
#include <iostream>    
using namespace std;    
class Test
{
private : 
    int data; 
    public : 
    Test() :data{0}
    {
        cout << "Test constructor (" << data << ")" << endl;
    }
    Test(int d) : data{ d }
    {
        cout << "Test constructor (" << data << ")" << endl; 
    }
    int get_data() const { return data; }
    ~Test()
    { 
        cout << "Test Destructor (" << data << ')' << endl; 
    }
};

// main function. 
int main()
{
   // It's fine if you use  make_shared and custom deleter like this
   std::shared_ptr<Test> ptr(new Test{1000},
            [](Test *ptr)
            {
                cout << "some Code that you want to execute "; 
                delete ptr;
            });
         return 0;
}
```

But if you use make_shared function you will get a compiler error

```
std::shared_ptr<Test> ptr = make_shared<Test>(1000,
            [](Test *ptr){
               cout << "some Code that you want to execute "; 
               delete ptr;
            });
```

Basically make_shared function is a wrapper for `new` and `delete` and if you want a custom deleter you have to provide you own `new` and `delete`