# How to use a lambda as a deleter in a c++ shared_ptr to create an object cache?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create a class that keeps a cache of objects.  The constructor will be private.  Instances will be created with a static function which returns shared_ptrs.  I want to use a deleter to remove the instance from the cache (a map) and it seems like I should be able to use a lambda but I cannot get it to work.

Here is what I have.  I commented out the line that creates the lambda:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <map>
#include <memory>


class CachedThing
{
    public:
        CachedThing(int size) {m_size=size;}
        int m_size;
        static std::map<int, std::shared_ptr<CachedThing>>  m_cache;

    public:
    static void DeleteFromCache(int size)
    {
    }

    static std::shared_ptr<CachedThing> CreateFromCache(int size)
    {
        auto it = CachedThing::m_cache.find(size);
        if (it != CachedThing::m_cache.end())
        {
            std::cout << "FOUND  " << size << std::endl;
            return it->second;
        }

        std::cout << "CREATE " << size << std::endl;

        //auto CacheDeleter = [] (int size) {CachedThing::DeleteFromCache(size);};

        auto f = std::make_shared<CachedThing>(size);  
        m_cache[size]=f;
        return f;
    }
};

std::map<int, std::shared_ptr<CachedThing>> CachedThing::m_cache {};

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Here we go..." << std::endl;

    {
        auto f1 = CachedThing::CreateFromCache(18);
    }
    auto f3 = CachedThing::CreateFromCache(20);
    auto f2 = CachedThing::CreateFromCache(18);
    auto f4 = CachedThing::CreateFromCache(20);
    auto f5 = CachedThing::CreateFromCache(20);

}
```

Comment: You cannot use `make_shared` to pass a custom deleter, look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34243367/how-to-pass-deleter-to-make-shared

Comment: I tried this and got "error: class template argument deduction failed"         auto f = std::shared_ptr(new DXFont(size), [] (int size) {CachedThing::DeleteFromCache(size);});

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That wouldn't work. The deleter of the `shared_ptr` is called once the last instance of the smart pointer is destroyed. In your case you store a copy of the `shared_ptr` in the cache: that means that you always have at least one instance, and the deleter is never called.

You may employ `weak_ptr`. This smart pointer has the access to the same counter that the `shared_ptr` uses to count instances, but `weak_ptr` has no ownership and doesn't increase/decrease the counter. You may create another `shared_ptr` instance out of a `weak_ptr` whenever at least one `shared_ptr` pointing on the object exists.

So the cache would store `weak_ptr`s, you may remove this `weak_ptr` from the deleter.

Here is the updated version that uses `weak_ptr`s:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <map>
#include <memory>


class CachedThing
{
    public:
        CachedThing(int size) {m_size=size;}
        int m_size;
        static std::map<int, std::weak_ptr<CachedThing>>  m_cache;

    public:
    static void DeleteFromCache(int size)
    {
    }

    static std::shared_ptr<CachedThing> CreateFromCache(int size)
    {
        auto it = CachedThing::m_cache.find(size);
        if (it != CachedThing::m_cache.end())
        {
            std::cout << "FOUND  " << size << std::endl;
            return it->second.lock();
        }

        std::cout << "CREATE " << size << std::endl;

        auto CacheDeleter = [] (CachedThing *obj) {
            std::cout << "Deleter called for " << obj->m_size << std::endl;
            CachedThing::DeleteFromCache(obj->m_size);
            delete obj;
        };

        std::shared_ptr<CachedThing> f(new CachedThing(size), CacheDeleter);  
        m_cache[size]=f;
        return f;
    }
};

std::map<int, std::weak_ptr<CachedThing>> CachedThing::m_cache {};

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Here we go..." << std::endl;

    {
        auto f1 = CachedThing::CreateFromCache(18);
    }
    auto f3 = CachedThing::CreateFromCache(20);
    auto f2 = CachedThing::CreateFromCache(18);
    auto f4 = CachedThing::CreateFromCache(20);
    auto f5 = CachedThing::CreateFromCache(20);

}
```

Comment: Ah ok I thought the deleter might be called whenever the shared_ptr use count goes down, but it sounds like you are saying it only gets called when the last instance is destroyed.  So using weak_ptrs I would periodically (on every get maybe) check the map for any weak_ptrs that are expired and remove them from the map.  Makes sense.

Comment: @Jimbo, no, you still can use this approach and remove an expired `weak_ptr` from the deleter (no need in periodical garbage collector). However the reason of having cache is not obvious from your code. What is the policy of keeping/removing the object from cache?

Comment: The intent is:  The first time an instance is needed for a given set of arguments it is instantiated, added to a cache, and a pointer to the instance is returned.  On subsequent requests for an instance matching the arguments, pointers to the cached object will be returned.  Instances will be stored in the cache as long as the returned pointers are in use.  There is no limit to the size of the cache.

Comment: @Jimbo, Ok, then my implementation shall solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

My final solution, based on Dmitry's answer, is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <map>
#include <memory>


class CachedThing
{
    private:
        CachedThing() = delete;
        CachedThing(int size) {m_size=size;}
        int m_size;
        static std::map<int, std::weak_ptr<CachedThing>>  m_cache;

    public:

    static std::shared_ptr<CachedThing> CreateFromCache(int size)
    {
        auto it = CachedThing::m_cache.find(size);
        if (it != CachedThing::m_cache.end())
        {
            std::cout << "FOUND  " << size << std::endl;
            return it->second.lock();
        }

        std::cout << "CREATE " << size << std::endl;

        auto CacheDeleter = [] (CachedThing *obj) {
            auto it=m_cache.find (obj->m_size);
            m_cache.erase ( it, m_cache.end() );  
            std::cout << "DELETE " << obj->m_size << std::endl;
            delete obj;
        };

        std::shared_ptr<CachedThing> f(new CachedThing(size), CacheDeleter);  
        m_cache[size]=f;
        return f;
    }
};

std::map<int, std::weak_ptr<CachedThing>> CachedThing::m_cache {};

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Here we go..." << std::endl;

    {
        auto f1 = CachedThing::CreateFromCache(18);
    }
    auto f3 = CachedThing::CreateFromCache(20);
    auto f2 = CachedThing::CreateFromCache(18);
    auto f4 = CachedThing::CreateFromCache(20);
    auto f5 = CachedThing::CreateFromCache(20);

}
```